# Disable Kerberos authentication for a particular user in CDH-5.15

Tags: kerberos, parquet, cloudera-cdh

I am using a 3rd party tool that can read data stored in parquet formaton hdfs and execute different functionalities on it. But this tool runs fine in environment which have Kerberos authentication disabled. I have Kerberos authentication enabled in my CDH-5.15  environment which cannot be disabled due to security reasons.

Is there a way to disable Kerberos authentication only for a particular user in CDH-5.15 ? Note that Parquet version that i have is 2.1.0

thanks

Comment: No, you can't. Security is security is security.

Comment: Besides, which kind of lousy "3rd party tool" has an HDFS connector that does not support Kerberos in 2019?!? I would guess some obsolete Python lib...

Comment: Are you sure the "tool" does not support Kerberos? Maybe it uses an HDFS client that _does_ support it (with proper config & valid Kerberos creds in the default cred cache) even if it was never documented or unit-tested. Nowadays even Python shitware should support Kerberos.